# What does this error mean SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, sql

I got this error message, I was trying to update my entry through this link but this message came up:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ID='8'' at line 1

```
    <?php 
$validform = true;
$ID = $_GET['ID'];
if ($ID=="") {
    echo "They didn't use GET. Are they POSTing anything? </br>";
    $rid = $_POST['ID'];
    if ($ID==''){
        $validform = false;
    } else {
        echo "The user submitted a POST. Update Category ID: ". $ID . "<br />";
        if (is_numeric($ID)) {
            if ($ID<=0 or $ID > 2147482647) {
                $validform = false;
                $riderrormessage = 'The Category ID must be greater than zero and less than 2147482647.';
            } else {
            //it's okay
            }
        } else {
            $validform = false;
            $IDerrormessage = 'The Category ID must be an integer.';
        }

        //****************************************************
        //Category
        $Cat = htmlentities($_POST['Cat']);
        if($Cat=='') {
            $validform = false;
            $Caterrormessage = 'Category is a required field.';
        } else {
            $emptyform = false;
            if (strlen($Cat)>100) {
                $validform = false;
                $Caterrormessage = 'The Category must be less than 100 characters long.';
            }
        }

        //*******************************************************
        //Description 

        $Description = htmlentities($_POST['Description']);
        if($Description=='') {
            $validform = false;
            $Descriptionerrormessage = 'Description is a required field.';
        } else {
            $emptyform = false;
            if (strlen($Description)>900) {
                $validform = false;
                $Descriptionerrormessage = 'Your Description must be less than 900 characters long.';
            }
        }



    //validation finished           
        if ($validform) {
            echo "Going to update Category ID: ". $ID . "<br />";
            echo "All data was valid.<br />";
            echo "Connecting to database server.<br />";
            try {
                //variable stores the connection -> $conn
                //PDO is a php data object -> helps prevent SQL injection
                //host = Database server host name
                //username = name of read/write user
                //password = that user's password
                $conn = new        PDO("mysql:host=Database info);
            } catch(PDOException $e) { //this should tell us if there was a connection problem
                echo "Error connecting to server: " . $e->getMessage();
                die;
            }
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "Connection to server succeeded.<br />";
            echo "Connecting to database Category...<br />";
            try {
                //if executing a query, NO USER ENTERED fields should be in query string!
                $conn->query("USE Database Table;");
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Error connecting to database: " . $e->getMessage();
                die;
            }
            echo "Connection to Category database succeeded.<br />";
            echo "Preparing SQL statement.<br />";
            //NO VARIABLES ALLOWED IN SQL
            //ALL USER ENTERED VALUES are going to be parameters -> variable  
         names that start with a colon
             $SQL = "UPDATE Category SET ID=:ID, Cat=:Cat,             
        Description=:Description";
            $SQL .= " WHERE ID=:ID";
            echo "This is the SQL statement: " . $SQL . "<br />";
            echo "Preparing to update Category record. <br />";
            try {
                $sth = $conn->prepare($SQL);
                $sth->bindParam(":ID", $ID);
                $sth->bindParam(":Cat", $Cat);
                $sth->bindParam(":Description", $Description);
                $sth->execute();
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Error adding Category record: " . $e->getMessage();
                die;
            }
            echo "Record updated in database. <br />";
            Header("Location: Header.php");

            die;
        }
    }
} else if (!is_numeric($ID)) {
    $validform = false;
}
echo "The user entered Category ID: ". $ID . "<br />";
    echo "Connecting to database server.<br />";
    try {
        //variable stores the connection -> $conn
        //PDO is a php data object -> helps prevent SQL injection
        //host = Database server host name
        //username = name of READ ONLY user
        //password = that user's password
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=Database Info);
    } catch(PDOException $e) { //this should tell us if there was a connection problem
        echo "Error connecting to server: " . $e->getMessage();
        die;
    }
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connection to server succeeded.<br />";
    echo "Connecting to database Category...<br />";
    try {
        //if executing a query, NO USER ENTERED fields should be in query string!
        $conn->query("USE Database Table;");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error connecting to database: " . $e->getMessage();
        die;
    }
    echo "Connection to Category database succeeded.<br />";
    //SQL statement will have user-entered data, so BIND needed
    $SQL = "SELECT ID, Cat, Description";
    $SQL .= "FROM Category WHERE ID=:ID;";
    try {
        $sth = $conn->prepare($SQL);
        $sth->bindParam(":ID", $ID);
        $sth->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error selecting Category records: " . $e->getMessage();
        die;
    }
    echo "Query executed successfully. <br />";
    //is there one record in the set?
    if($sth->rowCount()!=1) {
        echo "Error. No records were returned or more than one record was returned.<br />";
        $validform = false;
    } else {
        echo $sth->rowCount() . " records returned.<br />";
        $result = $sth->fetch();
        $ID = $result['ID'];
        $Cat = $result['Cat'];
        $Description = $result['Description'];

    }
    //$result is an array that holds the dataset


 if ($validform==false) {
echo "Data was invalid. Please contact technical support.";
  } else {
echo "User wants to update Category with Category ID=". $ID ."<br />";
 }
  ?>
```

Update Category Form

```
     <form action="Update.php" method="post">
      Category ID: <?php echo $ID; ?><input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php             echo $ID; ?>">
     <span style="color: red;"><?php echo $IDerrormessage; ?></span><br />


    Category Name: <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $Cat; ?>">
   <span style="color: red;"><?php echo $Caterrormessage; ?></span><br />


  Description: <textarea name="Description" style="width: 300px; height: 80px;">
  <?php echo $Description; ?></textarea><br />
   <span style="color: red;"><?php echo $Descriptionerrormessage; ?></span>

    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Confused on your comment Sami

Comment: `PDO("mysql:host=Database info)` that's a syntax error for one.

Comment: this is a typo question; Stack says it's off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$SQL = "SELECT ID, Cat, Description";
$SQL .= "FROM Category WHERE ID=:ID;";
```

There is a space missing here! So the `FROM` is not detected and the `WHERE` seems out of place.

This is why I would strongly suggest not to do this kind of linebreaking!
You will encounter this type of error freqently when you break the line within a string. I suggest you use an editor that has the feature to break the line visually at a specific position.

Comment: Should I get rid of the Where or is it just placed in the wrong spot? Basically when the user goes to update the category, the ID is basically saying, would you like to update ID 8 if that makes sense

Comment: Just add a space and you are fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! Is there a correct way to do the sql line breaking, I know you advise against it but I like seeing all my code without having to scroll over.

Comment: This conversation got entangled :D. Just as I commented above: Set it in your editors preferences that the text gets line-broken visually but not from a script-interpreter view.

Comment: I'm probably taking this way to personally, but just to improve my answering skills: Why did I get 2 downvotes?

Comment: Martin, I was also confused on why you received a downvote, your answer was correct.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a space before `FROM` in this part of the code:

```
$SQL = "SELECT ID, Cat, Description";
$SQL .= "FROM Category WHERE ID=:ID;";
```

The code is interpreting the query as:

```
SELECT ID, Cat, DescriptionFROM Category WHERE ID=:ID;
```

Which is saying to select a column named `DescriptionFROM` and alias it as `Category`.  Since there is no `FROM` clause, it is thrown off by the `WHERE` statement, which is why you're getting that error.

Adding a  after `Description` and before `FROM` will render the query correctly:

```
$SQL = "SELECT ID, Cat, Description ";
$SQL .= "FROM Category WHERE ID=:ID;";
```

Comment: Ohhh, what is the correct way to have a line break for the SQL statements

Comment: @LilyRose93 I don't use PHP, unfortunately, so I'm not sure if there's a string literal that you can use (e.g. `@""` in `C#`), but making sure you have a space at the end of each line should suffice.

Comment: The correct way is to set your editor to break the line visually without breaking it in a `\n` kind of way.